# Is it possible to assign the result of an SQL to a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, variables

Can I assign the result of an SQL select command to a local variable in ASP.NET?

Comment: You may want to accept a few answers to your previous questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar is what you are after.

Example:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 age FROM example_table");
var ageValue = command.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Scalar result: sure, just use ExecuteScalar.

Non-scalar: use a DataSet, or do some processing to build a collection of items containing the data you want

Comment: It's not finding the ExecuteScalar command :S I'm using System.Data.SqlClient;